# Python Unittest Mock - Reroute a function's write() to a temp dir?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm currently trying to write a unittest which checks whether or not a function has written an error log. For testing purposes, the error log is to be written to a temporary directory but I am unsure how I can re-route the location of a write() call using unittest.mock.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: Possibly consider monkey patching, as described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch .

Comment: Thanks. I refactored my code to include the file paths as instances variables and then reassigned them in the unittest to the temp directory. Problem solved!